# How do I compute the transition probability function?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have to reproduce the algorithm of a scientific article and have chosen [one](http://busoniu.net/files/papers/ifac08-elevators.pdf) that uses Reinforcement Learning.

However, I don't understand how to compute the  transition probability function ($f$) used in the iteration:

[image: Q-value iteration]

The article says:

> In order to run the Q-value iteration algorithm (Table 2), the
>   transition probability function f was first computed.

My question is: how was it computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition probability function is a property of the environment. This is one of the things you need to run a simulation. How you compute it is entirely up to you. You could make one up.

Comment: Thank you. Can I just take an arbitrary function or should I use some technique to evaluate a better function?

Comment: I recommend looking at the standard environments at http://library.rl-community.org